# Small but important tag excerpt change rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, tag-excerpt

The excerpt of [hwioauthbundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hwioauthbundle) now says:

> HWIOAuthBundle adds support for authenticating users via OAuth in Symfony2.

This is incorrect. It can be used by Symfony, not only Symfony 2. The current version doesn't even support Symfony 2.

While I understand this is a very small change (removing one character), it's a crucial difference. However, my change has been [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29398999).

Please help me understand what I should have done instead.

Answer (score 32):

I don't have the power to change the outcome, but that change should not have been rejected.

*However*, **you** **absolutely** **should have** **included an *edit description*** with the explanation that you've given here.

Without that context, you gave editors *no reason* not to reject it as an inconsequential and otherwise minor change. Reviewers need as much context as you can give them, *especially* in tag wiki edits (since reviewers usually aren't subject matter experts).

Answer (score 3):

Tag wiki excerpts must include usage guidance, which at least one of the rejection reasons indicates:

> Simply defining what a [tag] is rarely helps those using it unless the tag's name *itself* is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe **why** and **when** a tag should be used. [See the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for more guidance.

So, you need to include/describe the kind of questions that should use this tag, e.g.

> HWIOAuthBundle adds support for authenticating users via OAuth in Symfony. Use this tag for questions about using it to implement OAuth in Symfony applications.

In some cases it may seem redundant or unnecessarily verbose, but it is an explicit requirement for tag excerpts edit suggestions.

Once you have reached 20,000 reputation, you can make more trivial edits without needing to have them reviewed by other users.

Comment: Should we change this explicit requirement? A 'use tag X for questions about X' doesn't add any value. And the lack of such a useless sentence prevented me from making this tag correct.

Comment: @StephanVierkant It's not "use tax X for questions about X", but "use tag X for questions about **doing Y** in X". A subtle but important distinction, just like the one in your failed edit suggestion. Otherwise, any question about code not working when a user us developing said code in Visual Studio might require the Visual Studio tag, for example... even if the IDE is completely irrelevant to the problem. That's part of what the "usage guidance" requirement entails... an explanation of exactly when to use something.

Comment: For a top-level language, library, utility, etc. it is often unnecessary, but whether the requirement should be changed or not is a topic for another, separate question.

Comment: It says _should_, not _must_. Usage guidance is only necessary when there are multiple possible uses of the thing in question.

Comment: @EvgenKo423 Stack Overflow’s guidelines don’t conform to IETF RFC rules. There’s no implicit lack of “must-ness” due to its use of “should”. You won’t find the word “must” in any of the guidelines. It’s assumed that those reading are mature enough to follow them despite the lack of a commanding voice.

Comment: This may be a good reason to reject an edit that adds a new wiki excerpt without usage guidance, but if one already existed, it's not a good reason to reject an edit that fixes an error in it. (Nirvana fallacy/perfect is the enemy of good.)

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I agree, but that's a separate discussion.